# ASMX POST object with Enum .net Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enums, asmx

In the server I have this code:

```
public enum EnumFilter
 { 
    True = 0,
    False = 1,
    All = 2
 }

public class FiltroSeguroRequest
{        
    public EnumFilter Vigentes { get; set; }     
}
```

In the client I make an object literal to send as parameter in an ajax call with a POST to an ASMX Web Service:

```
this.request = { Vigentes: 2 };
```

As you can see i'm passing and integer to the Enum so at the server is transformed to an enum... but it doesn't work, cause is converted to a Boolean instead.

Comment: The second piece of code is javascript? Did you try {Vigentes: 'All'} instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL declaration for your enum should look like this:

```
<s:simpleType name="EnumFilter">
<s:restriction base="s:string">
    <s:enumeration value="True"/>
    <s:enumeration value="False"/>
    <s:enumeration value="All"/>
</s:restriction>
```

So, if you want to call it from javascript, your request should be:

```
this.request = { Vigentes: 'All' };
```